# How do I monitor for clicks on polygons with Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

My polygons are loaded dynamically from a .kml file using KMLLayer.

I need these polygons (on click) to link to a page.

Can anyone advise me or provide a solution please?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to show an info window on click, or do something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can just simply add a listerer to the polygon.

```
var polygon = google.maps.Polygon(....);
polygon.addListener('click', function(){

});
```

[Polygon reference](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Polygon)

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I put it in my code but I'm unsure what information needs to go inside Polygon(....); where the dots are?

Comment: If you load dynamically plygons from file you have to create a Polygon object with them. Then `var polygon` is that loaded and added to the map value.

Comment: The coordinates in the kml file don't even seem to be valid coordinates haha. Thanks for the help but I think I'm screwed on this one.

Answer (score 2):

If i'm not mistaken i think that features loaded from kml cannot have listeners attached to them.Please take a close look [here](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#KMLLayers)

Comment: "Note that you can't access these constituent objects directly, though they each provide click events which return data on those individual objects." - Makes me wonder

Comment: Thank you very much. I came back across this link and it was EXACTLY what I needed!

Comment: You are welcome.Please vote the answers you find useful.Cheers

Comment: Damn, I can't vote because of my reputation level. I'll vote you on my proper account when I'm home.