# Clickable / Linked polygons? Google Maps API + Fusion Tables / KML

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-fusion-tables

I found this Q/A that seemed to be the answer:

```
var polygon = google.maps.Polygon(....);
polygon.addListener('click', function(){

});
```

...but the problem is that I don't understand a word of it. I'm not even positive this is actually what I'm looking for.

What does the (....) stand for? Where would this pull the actual URL from? Would I add a column to my fusion table with the URL, and then somehow call a particular cell based on it's country code?

This is the code I'm currently using for my country polygons, pulling the KML from fusion tables.

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: '1LfVcxsno9k3l2zgKS_fwoyv9vc-ba7aoQEz0aKM'
    },
    styles: [{
        polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: '#5E5E5E',
        fillOpacity: 0.3
        }
      }]
    });
layer.setMap(map); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post a link to this documentation? (....) probably stands for "some parameters/coordintates go here"

Comment: Oh god, oops. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067534/how-do-i-monitor-for-clicks-on-polygons-with-google-maps-api-v3 It's just a very brief answer to another SO question. The person here asks the same question about the dots and the answer was: "If you load dynamically plygons from file you have to create a Polygon object with them. Then var polygon is that loaded and added to the map value." I don't really get that to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you are looking at the (....) would be replaced with a [PolygonOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolygonOptions) object, similar to the [FusionTablesOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayerOptions) that you are using to create your layer with.

An event is then bound to the polygon that was created.

However in your case you are not creating individual polygons, but instead creating a FusionTablesLayer.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10744426/1822046) gives an example for binding a click event listener to a FusionTablesLayer object.